# Spring Kafka Can't deserialize data [[]] from topic - No content to map due to end-of-input

Tags: java, spring-kafka

Recently added kafka to the project, it worked just fine until I tried to send not just string message but a custom object instead, did it all accordingly to Baeldung guide and can't get why it isn't working, the config code builds fine,  but when I add listener code to it it's not working. Also there are a lot of the exception messages and not that many of events, so I assume exception messages coming event without kafka messages themselves

Kafka config:

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.NewTopic;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnProperty;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafka;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.*;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer;
import paysys.persist.event.StatusUpdatedEvent;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@EnableKafka
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "status.topic.enabled")
public class KafkaConfig {

private final Environment environment;
private final String topicName = "payOperationStatusChanges";
private final String kafkaGroupId = "status";

public KafkaConfig(Environment environment) {
    this.environment = environment;
}

//TopicConfig

@Bean
public KafkaAdmin kafkaAdmin() {
    Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
    configs.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, environment.getProperty("sender.kafka.bootstrap-servers"));
    return new KafkaAdmin(configs);
}

@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "status.topic.enabled")
public NewTopic eventTopic() {
    return new NewTopic(topicName, 1, (short) 1);
}

//ProducerConfig

@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, StatusUpdatedEvent> producerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, environment.getProperty("sender.kafka.bootstrap-servers"));
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
}

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, StatusUpdatedEvent> statusKafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
}


//ConsumerConfig

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, StatusUpdatedEvent> consumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
    configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
            environment.getProperty("sender.kafka.bootstrap-servers"));
    configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG,
            kafkaGroupId);
    configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG,
            "earliest");
    configProps.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES,
            "*");
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(configProps, new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>(StatusUpdatedEvent.class));
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, StatusUpdatedEvent>
kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, StatusUpdatedEvent> factory =
            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    return factory;
}

}
```

And the listener:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnProperty;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import paysys.persist.event.StatusUpdatedEvent;

@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "status.topic.enabled")
public class StatusEventListener {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StatusEventListener.class);

    @KafkaListener(topics = "operationStatusChanges", groupId = "status", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void listenGroupFoo(StatusUpdatedEvent message) {
        log.info("Received status update event : {}", message);
    }

}
```

The exception:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition operationStatusChanges-0 at offset 1987. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't deserialize data [[]] from topic [operationStatusChanges]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: (byte[])""; line: 1, column: 0]
    at
```

Object I try to send:

```
public class StatusUpdatedEvent extends PayOperationEvent {

    public static final String STATUS_UPDATED_EVENT_TYPE = "statusUpdated";

    private final PayOperation.PayOperationStatus oldStatus;
    private final PayOperation.PayOperationStatus newStatus;

    public StatusUpdatedEvent(PayOperation.PayOperationStatus oldStatus, PayOperation.PayOperationStatus newStatus, PayOperation payOperation) {
        super(STATUS_UPDATED_EVENT_TYPE, payOperation);
        this.oldStatus = oldStatus;
        this.newStatus = newStatus;
    }

    public PayOperation.PayOperationStatus getOldStatus() {
        return oldStatus;
    }

    public PayOperation.PayOperationStatus getNewStatus() {
        return newStatus;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "StatusUpdatedEvent{" +
                "oldStatus=" + oldStatus +
                ", newStatus=" + newStatus +
                ", payOperation=" + this.getPayOperation() +
                '}';
    }
}
```

extended object:

```
public abstract class PayOperationEvent {
    private final String type;
    private final PayOperation payOperation;

    protected PayOperationEvent(String type, PayOperation payOperation) {
        this.type = type;
        this.payOperation = payOperation;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public PayOperation getPayOperation() {
        return payOperation;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PayOperationEvent{" +
                "type='" + type + '\'' +
                ", payOperation=" + payOperation.toString() +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like bad JSON; look at a record using the `kafka-console-consumer.sh`. Also edit the question to show your `StatusUpdatedEvent`.

Comment: @GaryRussell edited the question to show even objects

Comment: What about the record contents (using the command line tool)? Also, you will need a no-arg constructor and property setters, or Jackson annotations in order to deserialize that class.

Comment: @GaryRussell adding Jackson annotations actually did help, thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

When you deal with a KAFKA Consumer, you should have a better exception handler, especially for the Serialization/DeSerialization. If you are seeing the exception **"org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition operationStatusChanges-0 at offset 1987. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption."** again and again, that means, consumer is keep polling the data but not able to skip and continue to the next message. Add the following class and see, the issue is with only that offset message.

```
public void run() {
        try {
            Consumer<String, StatusUpdatedEvent> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(eventConsumerConfig.getEventConsumerConfig());
            consumer.subscribe(Collections.singleton(topicName));
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        ConsumerRecords<String, StatusUpdatedEvent> consumerRecords = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(5000));
                        for (TopicPartition partition : consumerRecords.partitions()) {
                            List<ConsumerRecord<String, StatusUpdatedEvent>> partitionRecords = consumerRecords.records(partition);
                            for (ConsumerRecord<String, StatusUpdatedEvent> record : partitionRecords) {

                                String eventMessage = record.value();

                            }
                        }
                    } catch (SerializationException serError) {
                        SkipPoisionPill.skip(topicName, serError.getMessage(), consumer);
                    } catch (Exception e2) {
                        continue;
                    }
                }

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

### SkipPoisionPill.class

```
public final class SkipPoisionPill {
    
    public static void skip(String topic, String serErrorMessage, Consumer<?, ?> consumer) {
        final Pattern offsetPattern = Pattern.compile("\\w*offset*\\w[ ]\\d+");
        final Pattern partitionPattern = Pattern.compile("\\w*" + topic + "*\\w[-]\\d+");
        
        try {
            Matcher mPart = partitionPattern.matcher(serErrorMessage);
            Matcher mOff = offsetPattern.matcher(serErrorMessage);

            mPart.find();
            Integer partition = Integer.parseInt(mPart.group().replace(topic + "-", ""));
            mOff.find();
            Long offset = Long.parseLong(mOff.group().replace("offset ", ""));
            consumer.seek(new TopicPartition(topic, partition), offset + 1);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Unable to seek past bad message. {}", ex.toString());
        }
    }
}
```